# Integral Inequality Question: Effect of Exponents

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations

Is it true that, if $\alpha q < (1-\alpha)q$ then $\int|k(x,y)|^{\alpha q}dy \leq \int|k(x,y)|^{(1-\alpha)q}dy$, where $k(x,y)$ is a positive measurable function?